# JsonConvert.Deserialize error 'No default constructor', but there is one

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am trying to Deserialize some Json, but I get this error:

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for type MyNamespace.MyClass. 
A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor 
with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor
attribute. Path 'timestamp', line 1, position 13.
```

Here is my class definition.  It clearly has a default constructor.  **This code works fine in a console app I tested it in, but fails in the Xamarin.Forms app.**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<MyOtherClass> Things { get; set; } 

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass()
    {
        Things = new List<MyOtherClass>();
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string RenderString { get { return Name + " : " + Status; } }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyOtherClass()
    {

    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: could you show your deserialize code and the json data ?i test your model,and work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As insane and unrelated as this sounds, the answer involves a linker switch. Something about the way class constructors are interpreted means that the Linking option found on the 'Android Options' tab of the Xamarin '.Android' project poperties must be set to 'Sdk Assemblies Only'.

[image]